# Invoking nosetests from within Emacs in a virtualenv

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv, nosetests

I have a project all of whose packages, incl. `nosetests` itself, are installed in a virtualenv specific to that project, stored under `~/.virtualenvs`. However, the `M-x nosetests-one` and `M-x nosetests-all` etc do not (obviously) even look into the virtualenv `bin` directory for commands, so these commands fail with an error message stating that the command `nosetests` could not be found; and even if that weren't the case, they'd be invoking the wrong `nosetests` binary because I need the tests to be invoked from within my virtualenv not the global environment.

I've tried several google searches to find a solution but I've not been able to find anything better than my existing hacky (but simple and reliable) approach of simply setting `nose-global-name` to a hardcoded value in the project's `.dir-locals.el` file:

```
((nil . ((nose-global-name . "~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/nosetests"))))
```

But, even though it's a viable solution, I'm hoping there's a more generic solution to this that doesn't require manual adjustment for every new project.

Comment: Not sure if you find solution, but have you considered virtualenvwrapper.el? It works for me with nosetests(and other virtualenv-related packages). You can find more information from its github page. https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el

Comment: I do use it all the time, but how is that related to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this code. It extracts the project name as the parent directory
of `(nose-find-project-root)`. In your case, it's `myproject`. Then it
sets `nose-global-name` temporarily to the one that you currently have (since the current project
name is `nosetests`).

```
(defun nosetests-all-virtualenv ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((nose-global-name
         (format 
          "~/.virtualenvs/%s/bin/nosetests"
          (car 
           (last 
            (delete 
             ""
             (split-string
              (nose-find-project-root)
              "/")))))))
    (nosetests-all)))
```

Comment: Thanks; I'll try and see if I can make that work somehow automatically :)